# How are the dimensions of the empennage determined for jetliners?

Tags: aircraft-design, control-surfaces

How is the height of the vertical and span of the horizontal stabilizers determined for different turbofan aircraft like the Airbus A380 and the Boeing 747-8?

What are the maximum forces (in kilograms or Newtons) acting on both the horizontal and vertical stabilizers for aircraft like the Airbus A380 or the Boeing 747-8?

Comment: That's practically four separate questions--pitching and yawing moments have different sets of causes. Consider https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45996/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-how-big-a-ventral-fin-should-be (which has an answer addressing one of your four questions: "it's complicated").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tail volume coefficients for the horizontal stabilizer ($C_H$) and vertical tail ($C_V$) for jet transports are 1.00 and 0.08 respectively.

[image]

For the horizontal stabilizer, for example, with the $C_H$ given, and the lever arm, [main] wing reference area ($S_W$), and [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(aeronautics)#Mean_aerodynamic_chord) known, the area can be calculated.

The shape, sweep angles, aspect ratio, etc., of each surface have their own rules.* Knowing the shape and area, the span or height is calculated.

**Example 1:** When the lever arm was reduced when the A319 was shortened to become the A318, they had to compensate by increasing the vertical stabilizer area, which meant a higher tail.

**Example 2:** Boeing designed the 757 and 767 simultaneously, so in order to reduce the fabrication and tooling costs, both shared the same tail, with the 757 tail shortened at the root (*[Flight](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1979/1979%20-%201749.html),* 1979).

[image]
(Own work)

---

* Reference and further reading on the aforementioned rules: [Empennage General Design](http://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/HOOU/AircraftDesign_9_EmpennageGeneralDesign.pdf) (.pdf), Hamburg University of Applied Sciences.

Comment: Another example and a very noticeable one is the Boeing 747SP which was  approximately 41 feet shorter than the 747-200.  Five feet was added to both the vertical stabilizer and each of the horizontal stabilizers.